# Having trouble initializing values on a pointer to an array of objects

Tags: arrays, class, object, pointers, initialization

I am having trouble initializing values onto a pointer to an array of objects. The structure i want to initialize is as follows:

```
 14 struct Checker
 15 {
 16  Checker();
 17   int m_money_in_register;
 18  int m_start_work;
 19  int m_time_checkout;
 20  Cust *m_cust;
 21 };
```

This is how im trying to initialize, Im just starting with one to make sure im doing it right:

```
119  Checker *checkers = new Checker[num_checkers];
120  for(int i =0; i < num_checkers; i++)
121  {
122   checkers->Checkers[i]->m_money_in_register = 500;
123   cout << checkers->Checkers[i]->m_money_in_register << endl;
124  }
```

What is the correct way to be doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out, it is done correctly as follows:

```
119 Checker *checkers = new Checker[num_checkers];
120  for(int i =0; i < num_checkers; i++)
121  {
122   checkers[i].m_money_in_register = 500;
123   cout << checkers[i].m_money_in_register << endl;
124  }
```